# KeyAdapter creating weird boxes

Tags: java, swing, shift

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(GameObject tempObject : handler.object){
        if(tempObject.getID() == ObjectID.Player){
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){ tempObject.setVelX(0); }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){ tempObject.setVelX(0); }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S){ tempObject.setVelY(0); }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){ tempObject.setVelY(0); }
        }
    }

    if(Game.getChat().isWorking()){
        Game.getChat().passText(e.getKeyChar(e.getKey));
        //.replaceAll("Space", " ").replaceAll("Period", ".").replaceAll("Backspace","").replaceAll("Shift","Shift").replaceAll("Slash","/").replaceAll("comma",",")
    }
}
```

}

This code basically checks when a user releases a key while typing something in the chat box for my game. Then it passes it onto a method that basically sets the text to be rendered in the game to that. This really doesn't matter though, the problem is this:

[image]

As you can see, those annoying boxes only appear when I have shift being released.

More code:
KeyInput:
http://pastebin.com/BM8yZ1i6
Game Class:
http://pastebin.com/vViQ23pS
Static Chat:
http: (slash slash) pastebin (dot) com/CgQE7SgN
ChatManager:
http: (slash slash) pastebin (dot) com/yVM5rdUs

Additional info:
when I System out the text that is being typed, the boxes are not boxes, they are question marks instead.

Comment: `KeyEvent.getKeyChar` is a parameterless method, and `e.getKey` wouldn't compile either... this can't be your actual code.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for faster help. Also for text fields, don't use key listeners. Use a `DocumentListener` or possibly a `DocumentFilter`, but I'm not sure which one would be more suitable, because your requirements are unclear.

Comment: I'm not using a text field, I'm basically creating a text kinda box (with Graphics) and rendering text over it, I added more code so what I am doing is understandable.

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: KeyBindings won't work for me as I'm using JFrame and keybindings requires a JPanel.

This is my key typed:
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
  if(Game.getChat().isWorking()){
   System.out.println("TAS: "+ e.getKeyChar());
   char c = e.getKeyChar();
   String cString = Character.toString(c);
   Game.getChat().passText(cString);
  }
 }

Everything works now, except when I press backspace, it returns a blank box which I'm starting to wonder why this is happening.